# Bug on datepicker query displaying html from ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

My jquery code :

```
$.datepicker.regional['fr'] = {
    closeText: 'Fermer',
    prevText: 'Précédent',
    nextText: 'Suivant',
    currentText: 'Aujourd\'hui',
    monthNames: ['Janvier','Février','Mars','Avril','Mai','Juin','Juillet','Août','Septembre','Octobre','Novembre','Décembre'],
    monthNamesShort: ['Janv.','Févr.','Mars','Avril','Mai','Juin','Juil.','Août','Sept.','Oct.','Nov.','Déc.'],
    dayNames: ['Dimanche','Lundi','Mardi','Mercredi','Jeudi','Vendredi','Samedi'],
    dayNamesShort: ['Dim.','Lun.','Mar.','Mer.','Jeu.','Ven.','Sam.'],
    dayNamesMin: ['D','L','M','M','J','V','S'],
    weekHeader: 'Sem.',
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    firstDay: 1,
    isRTL: false,
    showMonthAfterYear: false,
    yearSuffix: ''
};
$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['fr']);

    $("#debutChargementMini").datepicker();
    $("#finChargementMini").datepicker();
    $("#debutChargementReel").datepicker();
    $("#finChargementReel").datepicker();
    $("#debutLivraisonMax").datepicker();
    $("#finLivraisonMax").datepicker();
    $("#debutLivraisonReelle").datepicker();
    $("#finLivraisonReelle").datepicker();

$('searchForm').submit(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
});

 $(document).ready(function() {
  function eventFunction(){
      $.ajax({
        url: 'MODEL/ajaxSearchTransport.php',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $("#searchForm").serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            //$('tbody').html(data.table);
            //$('#ivalue').val(data.i);
        $('tbody').html(data.htmlContenu);
        $('#iValue').val(data.iValue);
            alert(data.test);
        },
        error: function() {
        alert('La requête AJAX n\'a pas abouti, contactez l\'administrateur'); }
      });
  };

  $('#numeroCommande').change(eventFunction);
  $('#rechercheVilleChargement').change(eventFunction);
  $('#rechercheVilleLivraison').change(eventFunction);


  });
```

When I change an input to call my ajax function, the content of calendar when I click on an input where I can is... what I get on the page by refreshing datas with html returned by ajax. As you can see below :

[image]

I tried to initialize datepicker after ajax success but it is the same...

Here is my HTML :

```
<form id="searchForm">
            <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
                    <label>Ville de chargement</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control collectes-ville text-center" name="rechercheVilleChargement" placeholder="Chargement" id="rechercheVilleChargement">
                    <label>Ville de livraison</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control collectes-ville text-center" name="rechercheVilleLivraison" placeholder="Livraison" id ="rechercheVilleLivraison">
        </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 form-group">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 form-group">
                    <label>Chargement mini</label>
                    <input type="text" id="debutChargementMini" class="form-control collectes-date-chargement-min text-center" name="debutChargementMini" placeholder="Date début" value="">
                    <label><-></label>
                    <input type="text" id="finChargementMini" class="form-control collectes-date-chargement-min text-center" name="finChargementMini" placeholder="Date fin" value=""> 
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 form-group">
                    <label>Chargement réel</label>
                    <input type="text" id="debutChargementReel" class="form-control collectes-date-chargement-min text-center" name="debutChargementReel" placeholder="Date début" value="">
                    <label><-></label>
                    <input type="text" id="finChargementReel" class="form-control collectes-date-chargement-min text-center" name="finChargementReel" placeholder="Date fin" value=""> 
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 form-group">
                    <label>Livraison maxi</label>
                    <input type="text" id="debutLivraisonMax" class="form-control collectes-date-chargement-min text-center" name="debutLivraisonMax" placeholder="Date début" value="">
                    <label><-></label>
                    <input type="text" id="finLivraisonMax" class="form-control collectes-date-chargement-min text-center" name="finLivraisonMax" placeholder="Date fin" value=""> 
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 form-group">
                    <label>Livraison réelle</label>
                    <input type="text" id="debutLivraisonReelle" class="form-control collectes-date-chargement-min text-center" name="debutLivraisonReelle" placeholder="Date début" value="">
                    <label><-></label>
                    <input type="text" id="finLivraisonReelle" class="form-control collectes-date-chargement-min text-center" name="finLivraisonReelle" placeholder="Date fin" value=""> 
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 form-group">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1 form-group">
                    <label>N° de commande</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control collectes-ville text-center" id="numeroCommande" name="numeroCommande" placeholder="N° Commande">
                    <label>Numéro d'OT</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control collectes-ville text-center" id="numeroOT" name="numeroOT" placeholder="Numero OT">
        </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 form-group">
                    <label>Statut</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control collectes-ville text-center" id="statut" name="statut" placeholder="Statut">
                    <label>Transporteur</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control collectes-ville text-center" id="transporteur" name="transporteur" placeholder="Transporteur">
        </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

I could give you my php file where ajax is going. But, it works very well. The only bug is on datepicker. If you need to see it, I will show you (it is long...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug is in fact not a real one.

Indeed, the bug error that I did was to write this :

```
$('tbody').html(data.htmlContenu);
```

In my javascript code.

If you want to return HTML from AJAX request, you need to create special div with special ids for that. Otherwise, frameworks will cause you some trouble. Because they are often using the DOM elements.

I hope this will help someone.